# Como fazer o STS solicitar o PIN do Usuario após LogOut

Tags: c#, webforms, autenticação, federation-authentication

Estou com Problemas para executar um logout da aplicação que usa STS.

Apos clicar no botão Logout, eu Expiro todos os cookies que eu tenho, até dou o comando signout do FederationAuthentication, mas ele nao solicita o PIN novamente

Segue código do logout

```
 protected void BtnLogoutClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WSFederationAuthenticationModule fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
            try
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Session.Abandon();
            }
            finally
            {
                fam.SignOut(true);
            }
            SignOutRequestMessage signOutRequest = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CORP.STS.Certificado"]), System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CORP.STS.UrlCliente"]);
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        }
```

Existe algo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheguei a seguinte conclusão:

```
 protected void BtnLogoutClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WSFederationAuthenticationModule fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
            try
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Session.Abandon();
            }
            finally
            {
                fam.SignOut(true);
            }
            var signOutRequest = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Corp.STS.Certificado"]), System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Corp.STS.UrlCliente"]);
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();

        }
```

Com o código acima é possível sim, expirar o usuário logado. O motivo de ele não pedir o PIN novamente é porque o PIN ja fora verificado anteriormente na mesma sessão do browser.
entao, enquanto opin ja estiver verificado no browser (não adianta limpar cache ou cookies) ele não solicitará PIN Novamente.